# Загрузучить файл (фото) на удаленный сервер?

Tags: php

Если пользователь в форму загружает файл и файл загружается на этот же сервер это легко.

Можно реализовать так чтобы например пользователь зашел на 1 сайт загружает и файл через какой-то код отправляется на другой сервер т.е. 2 сайт.

Какие вообще для этого функции используется? Полезна любая наводка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на 1 сервере принимаете файл, создаете сURL запрос ко 2-му серверу, через CURLFile передаете файл. на 2 сервере нужен скрипт, принимающий и сохраняющий файл, соответственно.